# Get document.referrer using typescript and angularjs

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I'm using Typescript with AngularJS 1.5 components.

The codebase I am working in strictly avoids calls to native JS, so things like `$log: ng.ILogService` are used instead of `console.log`, and `$timeout: ng.ITimeoutService` instead of `setTimeout`.

I am trying to get `document.referrer`, however `ng.IDocumentService` doesn't seem to have it, it is undefined. I've searched Google but have been unable to find anything so far.

Is there a way of retrieving `document.referrer` but in a typed way?

Comment: May anyone please explain to me why this might have been downvoted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at this with fresh eyes and realised that `IDocumentService` is a wrapper for a JQuery object, not for `document`.

I.e. for https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$document.

The correct syntax using the AngularJS TypeScript wrappers would be `this.$document[0]['referrer']`.